# Access VBA Run-time error 3078, or Type Mismatch on DCount function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, dcount

Objective:  I'm building VBA code to filter through an address table *SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest*.  I want to loop through first and see if the address is "valid".

- If it is not valid – export to different table.
- If it is valid – it enters another nested if/then within "valid" address rows:

  - If their ID, *external_nmad_id* matches the ID of the second table *1042s_FinalOutput_7*, I want to update one of the columns in the second table *box13c_Address*.
  - If it doesn't match an ID of the second table – it will be exported to a different table.

My problem is when I run my code it is returning

> Run-Time error 3078: cannot find table or query

(it's breaking at the line where I compare the value of the cell (as string) against the `DCount` of table 2). If I remove the quotes around it I get a different error:

> Type mismatch against the `DCount`

I feel like I'm missing something simple but can't tell what.  How can I get my code to match a string value called in `!external_nmad_id` against the rest of the table called in my string? `DCount("[ID]", StrSQL1)`

```vb
Public Sub EditFinalOutput2()

'set variables
Dim i As Long
Dim qs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ss As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSQL1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim IRSfileFormatKey As String
Dim external_nmad_id As String
Dim nmad_address_1 As String
Dim nmad_address_2 As String
Dim nmad_address_3 As String
Dim mytestwrite As String

'open reference set
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qs = db.OpenRecordset("SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest")
'Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_7")
'Set StrSQL1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID 
'FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")

With qs.Fields
intCount = qs.RecordCount - 1
For i = 0 To intCount

    If (IsNull(!nmad_address_1) Or (!nmad_address_1 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_1 = !Webir_Country) And IsNull(!nmad_address_2) Or (!nmad_address_2 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_2 = !Webir_Country) And IsNull(!nmad_address_3) Or (!nmad_address_3 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_3 = !Webir_Country)) Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_ToBeReviewed SELECT SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"

    Else:
        Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_7")
        Set StrSQL1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")
        If !external_nmad_id = DCount("[ID]", StrSQL1) Then
                ss.Edit
                ss.Fields("box13c_Address") = qs.Fields("nmad_address_1") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_2") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_3")
                ss.Update

        Else:   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_NotUsed SELECT SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"
                DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        End If

    End If

qs.MoveNext
Next i

End With

'close reference set
qs.Close
Set qs = Nothing
ss.Close
Set ss = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the DCount function cannot operate directly against a Recordset.

You are declaring `StrSQL1` as a RecordSet object and setting it to a RecordSet based on your `Select` statement.

```
Set StrSQL1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")
```

You are then trying to pass this RecordSet to the `DCount` function which cannot accept a RecordSet object as the `Domain` parameter.  As you can see in MSDN the [DCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dcount) function requires a String parameter in the second position to define the "query" that you wish to "Count".  Hence the 3078 error.  When you remove the quotes around `[ID]` in your DCount line, you get Type Mismatch as a compile error because `[ID]` is not a String or String variable.

After you resolve that, you might want to reconsider your `If` statement.  You haven't provided a sample of what kind of value `!external_nmad_id` will contain, other than the fact that it is a String value.  The `DCount` function is going to return the number of rows found in the Domain (query) that you told it to count, so it appears you will be comparing a string (which may possibly contain alpha characters) to a number.  Access will implicitly convert the `DCount` numeric result to a String for the sake of the comparison, but if your `!external_nmad_id` String is truly 10 characters or contains alpha characters, they will never match.

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't realize that DCount cannot operate directly against a recordset.  After knowing that I just had to change stratagy.  I was able to use DCount to do the same query so now I removed the StrSQL and instead it's " = DCount("RIGHT([IRSfileFormatKey], 10)", "1042s_FinalOutput_7")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a VBA recordset inside a domain aggregate like `DCount` as a string literal is required for table/query name argument. Simply save your query and then reference it by name in `DCount`.

**SQL** *(save as query)*

```
SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;
```

**VBA**

```vb
If !external_nmad_id = DCount("[ID]", "mySavedQuery") Then
   ...
End If
```